# Append packages to the default exported system packages

Tags: maven, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, pax

I'm using maven-pax-plugin in my OSGI project. and I use pax-provision to run the project. In some bundles I use javafx packages. I want to add javafx packages to exported system packages but I don't find a way to do it. I found this link :
 [specify additional java packages to be exported by System Bundle](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxrunner/System+packages)

But I don't see how to use it with pax-provision. 
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me. For example, I have a need to add `sun.misc` to the system packages, so I do this when running maven:

```
mvn pax:run -DsystemPackages=sun.misc
```

According to the doc you reference, this can be a comma-separated list of packages.